# low performance of services when using third party resources (CDN) with GWT

Tags: java, performance, gwt, cdn

The company i work for wanted to enhance performance of the whole system by using CDN for the static resources (js - images - css), but for our own surprise it actually made the whole performance worse. (from 850ms to 1400ms avg response time).

When we monitored the requests that took the highest avg response time we found that the services response time is now doubled (eg . login service : from 400ms without CDN to 900ms with CDN ). the resources itself was better than normal (from 200+ms to 20- ms) that means that CDN should indeed boost the performance. but due to the low performance of the services the system overall perform lower at the end. I really need to know why would that happen

Comment: When you say "login service" are you referring to the server-side service that executes the login? In which way can this be service be related to the static content? Or you are talking here about the end user monitoring results? Some explanation would be needed here in order to help..

Comment: We are using jmeter to analysis the performance from the client side view.  So the data is counted since the client request to the server till the server respond to the client.  In short.  It is the time of client side call + server side service

Comment: Maybe I am getting something wrong here, but static resources are delivered in separate HTTP requests.. This means when you execute the login service for example first the main HTTP request is sent to perform the actual login, and then when the HTML response is back the static resources are retrieved.. Same in JMeter, you would have these requests separated (first execute the request that performs the real work, then load the static resources).. I can not understand what and how you are measuring, since your "main" HTTP request should have nothing to do with loading of those resources?

Comment: You are right in what you said, static HTTP requests shouldn't affect other requests. but it affects the server. When I looked deeper to the the performance issue. I found that the main reason behind the services avg response time increase was due that the server now can take more services since the resources was loaded away from it. so the amount of heavy data across the same response time has increased( like accessing DB, System File, ...). It is like running 100 meter while holding 30k weights .